# error: ‘nl_socket_alloc’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sockets

I get tis error when I'm compiling the following code,the point is that I know there is some error with the declaration of  nl_socket_alloc but I cannot see where exactly I screw it up.

the compiler complains when I inicializate the sockets in the .cpp, so I'm guessing that maybe they're bad declared.

Thanks in advance

```
#include "ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.h"
#include "ibrcommon/net/vsocket.h"
#include "ibrcommon/Logger.h"

#include <netlink/netlink.h>
#include <netlink/route/link.h>
#include <netlink/route/addr.h>
#include <netlink/route/rtnl.h>
#include <netlink/socket.h>
#include <netlink/msg.h>
//#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>

namespace ibrcommon
{
    static int nl3_callback(struct nl_msg *msg, void *arg)
    {
        NetLink3Manager *m = static_cast<NetLink3Manager *>(arg);
        NetLink3ManagerEvent evt(msg);
        m->callback(evt);
        return 0;
    }

    void add_addr_to_list(struct nl_object *obj, void *data)
    {
        char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+5];
        std::list<vaddress> *list = static_cast<std::list<vaddress>*>(data);

        struct nl_addr *naddr = rtnl_addr_get_local((struct rtnl_addr *) obj);
        int ifindex = 0;
        int scope = rtnl_addr_get_scope((struct rtnl_addr *) obj);

        if (scope == rtnl_str2scope("link"))
            ifindex = rtnl_addr_get_ifindex((struct rtnl_addr *) obj);

        if (naddr)
        {
            int family = nl_addr_get_family(naddr);
            nl_addr2str( naddr, buf, sizeof( buf ) );
            vaddress vaddr(vaddress::Family(family), vaddress::strip_netmask(std::string(buf)), ifindex, false);
            list->push_back( vaddr );
        }

        struct nl_addr *baddr = rtnl_addr_get_broadcast((struct rtnl_addr *) obj);

        if (baddr)
        {
            int family = nl_addr_get_family(baddr);
            nl_addr2str( baddr, buf, sizeof( buf ) );
            vaddress vaddr(vaddress::Family(family), vaddress::strip_netmask(std::string(buf)), ifindex, true);
            list->push_back( vaddr );
        }
    }

    NetLink3Manager::NetLink3Manager()
     : _refresh_cache(false), _running(true), _sock(NULL)
    {
        // initialize the sockets
        _nl_notify_sock = nl_socket_alloc();//=>First error
        _nl_query_sock = nl_socket_alloc();//=>Second error

        // disable seq check for notify socket
        nl_socket_disable_seq_check(_nl_notify_sock);

        // define callback method
        nl_socket_modify_cb(_nl_notify_sock, NL_CB_VALID, NL_CB_CUSTOM, nl3_callback, this);

        // connect to routing netlink protocol
        nl_connect(_nl_notify_sock, NETLINK_ROUTE);
        nl_connect(_nl_query_sock, NETLINK_ROUTE);

        // init route messages
        nl_socket_add_memberships(_nl_notify_sock, RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR);

//      IPv6 requires further support in the parsing procedures!
//      nl_socket_add_membership(_nl_notify_sock, RTNLGRP_IPV6_IFADDR);
        nl_socket_add_memberships(_nl_notify_sock, RTNLGRP_LINK);

        // create a cache for the links
        if (rtnl_link_alloc_cache(_nl_query_sock, AF_UNSPEC, &_link_cache) < 0)
        {
            nl_socket_free(_nl_notify_sock);
            nl_socket_free(_nl_query_sock);
            // error
            throw ibrcommon::vsocket_exception("netlink cache allocation failed");
        }

        // create a cache for addresses
        if (rtnl_addr_alloc_cache(_nl_query_sock, &_addr_cache) < 0)
        {
            nl_socket_free(_nl_notify_sock);
            nl_socket_free(_nl_query_sock);
            // error
            nl_cache_free(_link_cache);
            _link_cache = NULL;
            throw ibrcommon::vsocket_exception("netlink cache allocation failed");
        }

        // create a new socket for the netlink interface
        _sock = new ibrcommon::vsocket();
    }

    NetLink3Manager::~NetLink3Manager()
    {
        stop();
        join();

        // destroy the socket for the netlink interface
        delete _sock;

        nl_cache_free(_addr_cache);
        nl_cache_free(_link_cache);

        nl_socket_free(_nl_notify_sock);
        nl_socket_free(_nl_query_sock);
    }

    const std::string NetLink3Manager::getInterface(int index) const
    {
        char buf[256];
        rtnl_link_i2name(_link_cache, index, (char*)&buf, sizeof buf);
        return std::string((char*)&buf);
    }

    const std::list<vaddress> NetLink3Manager::getAddressList(const vinterface &iface, const vaddress::Family f)
    {
        ibrcommon::MutexLock l(_call_mutex);

        if (_refresh_cache)
        {
            nl_cache_free(_addr_cache);
            nl_cache_free(_link_cache);

            // create a cache for the links
            if (rtnl_link_alloc_cache(_nl_query_sock, AF_UNSPEC, &_link_cache) < 0)
            {
                // error
                throw ibrcommon::vsocket_exception("netlink cache allocation failed");
            }

            // create a cache for addresses
            if (rtnl_addr_alloc_cache(_nl_query_sock, &_addr_cache) < 0)
            {
                // error
                nl_cache_free(_link_cache);
                _link_cache = NULL;
                throw ibrcommon::vsocket_exception("netlink cache allocation failed");
            }

            // mark the cache as refreshed
            _refresh_cache = false;
        }

        std::list<vaddress> addresses;

        struct rtnl_addr *filter = rtnl_addr_alloc();
        const std::string i = iface.toString();
        rtnl_addr_set_ifindex(filter, rtnl_link_name2i(_link_cache, i.c_str()));

        if (f == vaddress::VADDRESS_UNSPEC)
        {
            rtnl_addr_set_family(filter, AF_INET6);
            nl_cache_foreach_filter(_addr_cache, (struct nl_object *) filter,
                                    add_addr_to_list, &addresses);

            rtnl_addr_set_family(filter, AF_INET);
            nl_cache_foreach_filter(_addr_cache, (struct nl_object *) filter,
                                    add_addr_to_list, &addresses);
        }
        else
        {
            rtnl_addr_set_family(filter, f);
            nl_cache_foreach_filter(_addr_cache, (struct nl_object *) filter,
                                    add_addr_to_list, &addresses);
        }

        rtnl_addr_put(filter);

        return addresses;
    }

    void NetLink3Manager::callback(const NetLink3ManagerEvent &lme)
    {
        // ignore if the event is unknown
        if (lme.getType() == LinkManagerEvent::EVENT_UNKOWN) return;

        // ignore if this is an wireless extension event
        if (lme.isWirelessExtension()) return;

        // need to refresh the cache
        {
            ibrcommon::MutexLock l(_call_mutex);
            _refresh_cache = true;
        }

        // print out some debugging
        IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_DEBUG(10) << lme.toString() << IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_ENDL;

        // notify all subscribers about this event
        raiseEvent(lme);
    }

    void NetLink3Manager::run()
    {
        // add netlink fd to vsocket
        _sock->add(nl_socket_get_fd(_nl_notify_sock));

        try {
            while (_running)
            {
                std::list<int> fds;
                _sock->select(fds, NULL);

                nl_recvmsgs_default(_nl_notify_sock);
            }
        } catch (const vsocket_exception&) {
            // stopped / interrupted
            IBRCOMMON_LOGGER(error) << "NetLink connection stopped" << IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_ENDL;
        }
    }

    void NetLink3Manager::__cancellation()
    {
        _running = false;
        _sock->close();
    }

    /** read a netlink message from the socket and create a new netlink event object **/
    NetLink3ManagerEvent::NetLink3ManagerEvent(struct nl_msg *msg)
     : _type(EVENT_UNKOWN), _state(0), _wireless(false)
    {
        int attrlen, nlmsg_len, rta_len, rtl;
        struct rtattr *attr;
        struct rtattr *rth;
        struct ifaddrmsg *ifa;
        struct ifinfomsg *ifi;
        struct nlmsghdr *nlh;

        // cast netlink message
        nlh = nlmsg_hdr(msg);

        switch (nlh->nlmsg_type)
        {
            case RTM_BASE:
            {
                ifi = (struct ifinfomsg *) NLMSG_DATA(nlh);

                nlmsg_len = NLMSG_ALIGN(sizeof(struct ifinfomsg));
                attrlen = nlh->nlmsg_len - nlmsg_len;

                if (attrlen < 0) break;

                attr = (struct rtattr *) (((char *) ifi) + nlmsg_len);

                rta_len = RTA_ALIGN(sizeof(struct rtattr));
                while (RTA_OK(attr, attrlen))
                {
                    size_t rta_length = RTA_PAYLOAD(attr);

                    switch (attr->rta_type)
                    {
                    case IFLA_IFNAME:
                        _interface = ibrcommon::vinterface( std::string((char*)RTA_DATA(attr), rta_length) );
                        _type = EVENT_LINK_STATE;
                        break;

                    case IFLA_OPERSTATE:
                    {
                        char s;
                        ::memcpy(&s, (char*)RTA_DATA(attr), 1);
                        _state = s;
                        break;
                    }

                    case IFLA_WIRELESS:
                        _wireless = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        _attributes[attr->rta_type] = std::string((char*)RTA_DATA(attr), rta_length);
                        break;
                    }

                    attr = RTA_NEXT(attr, attrlen);
                }
                break;
            }

            case RTM_NEWADDR:
            {
                ifa = (struct ifaddrmsg *) NLMSG_DATA(nlh);
                rth = IFA_RTA(ifa);
                rtl = IFA_PAYLOAD(nlh);

                // parse all attributes
                while (rtl && RTA_OK(rth, rtl))
                {
                    switch (rth->rta_type)
                    {
                        // local address
                        case IFA_LOCAL:
                        {
                            char address[256];

                            uint32_t ipaddr = htonl(*((uint32_t *)RTA_DATA(rth)));
                            sprintf(address, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipaddr >> 24) & 0xff, (ipaddr >> 16) & 0xff, (ipaddr >> 8) & 0xff, ipaddr & 0xff);

                            _address = ibrcommon::vaddress(ibrcommon::vaddress::VADDRESS_INET, std::string(address));
                            _type = EVENT_ADDRESS_ADDED;
                            break;
                        }

                        // interface name
                        case IFA_LABEL:
                        {
                            //char name[IFNAMSIZ];
                            char *name = (char *)RTA_DATA(rth);
                            _interface = ibrcommon::vinterface(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    rth = RTA_NEXT(rth, rtl);
                }
                break;
            }

            case RTM_DELADDR:
            {
                ifa = (struct ifaddrmsg *) NLMSG_DATA(nlh);
                rth = IFA_RTA(ifa);
                rtl = IFA_PAYLOAD(nlh);

                // parse all attributes
                while (rtl && RTA_OK(rth, rtl))
                {
                    switch (rth->rta_type)
                    {
                        // local address
                        case IFA_LOCAL:
                        {
                            char address[256];

                            uint32_t ipaddr = htonl(*((uint32_t *)RTA_DATA(rth)));
                            sprintf(address, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipaddr >> 24) & 0xff, (ipaddr >> 16) & 0xff, (ipaddr >> 8) & 0xff, ipaddr & 0xff);

                            _address = ibrcommon::vaddress(ibrcommon::vaddress::VADDRESS_INET, std::string(address));
                            _type = EVENT_ADDRESS_REMOVED;
                            break;
                        }

                        // interface name
                        case IFA_LABEL:
                        {
                            //char name[IFNAMSIZ];
                            char *name = (char *)RTA_DATA(rth);
                            _interface = ibrcommon::vinterface(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    rth = RTA_NEXT(rth, rtl);
                }
                break;
            }

            default:
                IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_DEBUG(10) << "unknown netlink type received: " << nlh->nlmsg_type << IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_ENDL;
                break;
        }
    }

    NetLink3ManagerEvent::~NetLink3ManagerEvent()
    {
    }

    const ibrcommon::vinterface& NetLink3ManagerEvent::getInterface() const
    {
        return _interface;
    }

    const ibrcommon::vaddress& NetLink3ManagerEvent::getAddress() const
    {
        return _address;
    }

    unsigned int NetLink3ManagerEvent::getState() const
    {
        return _state;
    }

    bool NetLink3ManagerEvent::isWirelessExtension() const
    {
        return _wireless;
    }

    LinkManagerEvent::EventType NetLink3ManagerEvent::getType() const
    {
        return _type;
    }

    const std::string NetLink3ManagerEvent::toString() const
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "NetLinkManagerEvent on " << getInterface().toString() << "; Type: " << getType();

        switch (getType())
        {
        case EVENT_LINK_STATE:
            ss << "; State: " << getState();
            break;

        case EVENT_ADDRESS_ADDED:
            ss << "; Address added: " << getAddress().toString();
            break;

        case EVENT_ADDRESS_REMOVED:
            ss << "; Address removed: " << getAddress().toString();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        };

        return ss.str();
    }

    void NetLink3ManagerEvent::debug() const
    {
//      for (std::map<int, std::string>::const_iterator iter = attr.begin(); iter != attr.end(); iter++)
//      {
//          std::stringstream ss;
//          const std::string &value = (*iter).second;
//
//          for (std::string::const_iterator si = value.begin(); si != value.end(); si++)
//          {
//              const char &c = (*si);
//              ss << std::hex << "0x" << (int)c << " ";
//          }
//
//          IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_DEBUG(10) << (*iter).first << ": " << ss.str() << IBRCOMMON_LOGGER_ENDL;
//      }
    }
} /* namespace ibrcommon */
```

The eclipse output:

```
./ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:66:37: error: ‘nl_socket_alloc’ was not declared in this scope
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:70:46: error: ‘nl_socket_disable_seq_check’ was not declared in this scope
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:73:85: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int nl_socket_modify_cb(nl_handle*, nl_cb_type, nl_cb_kind, nl_recvmsg_msg_cb_t, void*)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:76:44: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int nl_connect(nl_handle*, int)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:77:43: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int nl_connect(nl_handle*, int)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:80:65: error: ‘nl_socket_add_memberships’ was not declared in this scope
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:87:68: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘nl_cache* rtnl_link_alloc_cache(nl_handle*)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:89:34: error: ‘nl_socket_free’ was not declared in this scope
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:96:57: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘nl_cache* rtnl_addr_alloc_cache(nl_handle*)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:98:34: error: ‘nl_socket_free’ was not declared in this scope
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual ibrcommon::NetLink3Manager::~NetLink3Manager()’:
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:121:33: error: ‘nl_socket_free’ was not declared in this scope
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp: In member function ‘virtual const std::list<ibrcommon::vaddress> ibrcommon::NetLink3Manager::getAddressList(const ibrcommon::vinterface&, ibrcommon::vaddress::Family)’:
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:142:69: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘nl_cache* rtnl_link_alloc_cache(nl_handle*)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:149:58: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘nl_cache* rtnl_addr_alloc_cache(nl_handle*)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void ibrcommon::NetLink3Manager::run()’:
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:213:46: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int nl_socket_get_fd(nl_handle*)’
../ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.cpp:221:40: error: cannot convert ‘ibrcommon::nl_sock*’ to ‘nl_handle*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int nl_recvmsgs_default(nl_handle*)’
make: *** [ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net/NetLink3Manager.o] Error 1
```

There the headers of the function NetLink3Manager.h

```
#ifndef NETLINK3MANAGER_H_
#define NETLINK3MANAGER_H_

#include "ibrcommon/net/LinkManager.h"
#include "ibrcommon/thread/Mutex.h"
#include "ibrcommon/thread/Thread.h"
#include "ibrcommon/net/vsocket.h"

#include <netlink/netlink.h>
#include <netlink/socket.h>
#include <netlink/route/link.h>
#include <netlink/msg.h>

namespace ibrcommon
{
    class NetLink3ManagerEvent : public LinkManagerEvent
    {
    public:
        NetLink3ManagerEvent(struct nl_msg *msg);
        virtual ~NetLink3ManagerEvent();

        virtual const ibrcommon::vinterface& getInterface() const;
        virtual const ibrcommon::vaddress& getAddress() const;
        virtual unsigned int getState() const;
        virtual EventType getType() const;

        virtual bool isWirelessExtension() const;

        void debug() const;
        const std::string toString() const;

    private:
        EventType _type;
        unsigned int _state;
        bool _wireless;
        ibrcommon::vinterface _interface;
        ibrcommon::vaddress _address;
        std::map<int, std::string> _attributes;
    };

    class NetLink3Manager : public ibrcommon::LinkManager, public ibrcommon::JoinableThread
    {
        friend class LinkManager;

    public:
        virtual ~NetLink3Manager();

        const std::string getInterface(int index) const;
        const std::list<vaddress> getAddressList(const vinterface &iface, const vaddress::Family f);

        class parse_exception : public Exception
        {
        public:
            parse_exception(string error) : Exception(error)
            {};
        };

        void callback(const NetLink3ManagerEvent &evt);

    protected:
        void run();
        void __cancellation();

    private:
        NetLink3Manager();

        struct nl_sock *_nl_notify_sock;
        struct nl_sock *_nl_query_sock;

        // local link cache
        struct nl_cache *_link_cache;
        struct nl_cache *_addr_cache;

        // mutex for the link cache
        ibrcommon::Mutex _call_mutex;

        bool _refresh_cache;
        bool _running;

        ibrcommon::vsocket *_sock;
    };
} /* namespace ibrcommon */
#endif /* NETLINK3MANAGER_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the first error and work your way down.  Firstly, is the function `nl_socket_alloc()` declared in any of the header files that you `#include`?  The way to find this out is the grep through those header files (they'll be somewhere on your system), looking for that symbol, and ensuring that the file you find it in is explicitly `#include`-ed.

Apply this strategy to the other missing symbols.

If you've included the file, the function `nl_socket_alloc` may be declared in the global namespace, in which case you may choose to refer to it as `::nl_socket_alloc` (since you're defining a non-global namespace.

Hope these suggestions point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

somehow necro - but I just stumbled over the same issue - so maybe this can help someone.

First of all: you need to install the libnetlink development headers.
On my ancient Debian 8 box

```
> sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
```

does the trick.

The documentation of the netlink library contains a part about the [library structure](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html#_linking_to_this_library). In this part you can find all information about required headers and how to link against the library. It basically boils down to include **netlink/netlink.h**. But sometimes (as on my Debian box) the devel package is installed but the directory containing the header files are not part of the default search path. You could run a find over your entire filesystem looking for netlink.h - this could give you a wrong direction (of course - if you dig out something using find you would always check twice to include the right file). But there is a more systematic approach available...

Provided you run a box using the Debian packaging system, you can check what netlink libraries are installed:

```
> dpkg --list libnl*
...
ii  libnl-3-200:amd64               3.2.24-2             amd64                library for dealing with netlink sockets
ii  libnl-3-dev                     3.2.24-2             amd64                development library and headers for libnl-3
un  libnl-dev                       <none>               <none>               (no description available)
ii  libnl-genl-3-200:amd64          3.2.24-2             amd64                library for dealing with netlink sockets - generic netlink
ii  libnl-route-3-200:amd64         3.2.24-2             amd64                library for dealing with netlink sockets - route interface
un  libnl2-dev                      <none>               <none>               (no description available)
un  libnl3-dev                      <none>               <none>               (no description available)
```

The one(s) with the leading *ii* are the relevant ones. Now use dpkg to get a list of the files provided by the package (and filter for the required one):

```
> dpkg  -L  libnl-3-dev | grep  "netlink\.h"

/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/netlink.h
```

As */usr/include/* is part of the default include paths (you can check the paths used by gcc using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940271/7525492)) you would need to add the prefix **libnl3** to your include statements. To prevent yourself from the need to change the includes if the library version changes, simply add */usr/include/libnl3* to your include path. For gcc this can be done using the [flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

```
-I /usr/include/libnl3
```

and for a cmake based build system just add a *include_diretories()* directive:

```
include_directories("/usr/include/libnl3")
```