# Finding out what the GCC include path is

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to programmatically find the `#include` path on Linux, which as I understand it, in practice means finding what GCC considers it to be. (Is that quite true? How does Clang do it?)

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html some of the components involve the CPU architecture and the GCC version; the latter in particular seems tricky; I suppose it could be obtained by running `gcc --version` and parsing the output (or `gcc -v`), but this seems inelegant at best and fragile at worst. Doing it from within one's code assuming one's program is being compiled with GCC might be another option, but it would require depending on that assumption.

What's the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

The command

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
```

will show the include path in use.

Comment: does `which gcc` command on bash do the same stuff?

Comment: Is the `echo |` necessary?

Comment: The `cpp -Wp,-v` command waits for some input. The `echo |` saves the user needing `Ctrl + D` or `Ctrl + C` to return to shell.

Comment: `echo | cpp -xc++ -Wp,-v` would give the C++ include paths.

Comment: And `gcc -Xlinker --verbose` will show the linker search paths.

Comment: `gcc -E -Wp,-v -xc /dev/null` <- This version does not require any shell (Use `g++ -E -Wp,-v -xc++ /dev/null` for C++)

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure what you mean by the *recommended* way to find the include path.  The *standard* way is as given below (for c and c++):

```
$ `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
^C
$ `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.7
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
^C
```

Comment: So, which one is the exact path?

Comment: @jay C and C++ have different include paths, pay attention to prog-name.