# how to view #include with <> directories

Tags: c, include-path

I'm aware that when using `#include <file>` the compiler will search in defined system directories for `file`. How can I view these directories?

I ask because I added a directory with a bunch of header files into /usr/local/include, and when I `#include <file>` the compiler still says `error: unknown type name ‘TPM_TAG’`. I suspect that /usr/local/include isn't in the compiler's list of directories to search.

Thanks!

Comment: If the file wasn't found you would have a fatal error so that is not the problem

Comment: You can use the `-I` flag to pass include directories.

Comment: He might still have an instance of a header file in /usr/include, and a newer version in /usr/local/include.

Comment: It depends on what compiler you're using. With gcc, `gcc -v` should show you where it's looking.

Comment: I have a directory full of header files that I want to use in my project. These header files assume that they are in a directory recognized by gcc (because they include each other with `#include <file>`). So I put this directory in /usr/local/include and included them with `#include<file>`, and I get the `unknown type name` error. I tried removing my #include statement to see what would happen, and I got the same error. This makes me think the compiler is not finding the directory of header files in /usr/local/include.

@KeithThompson, which option of that output provides the directory?

Comment: In the output of `gcc -v` look for "`#include "..." search starts here:`" and "`#include <...> search starts here:`". You can also examine the preprocessor output produced by `gcc -E` to see exactly which files are included. As I said, this depends on what compiler you're using; if you're looking for information about gcc in particular, please update your question to say so and add the "gcc" tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can search in different ways depending on the compiler, with gcc for example it is possible to check where the compiler looks for files by using

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

or you can compile your c file with the option `gcc -H`, for example with `gcc -H -c myfile.c`

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you're using a standard header or a local, user-defined header. Maybe try to use #include "file" and make the header file local instead and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -I. yourfile.c
```

`-I` introduce path of `include files`, So if you have some include file in your subdirectory such as sort/ list/ and so on,you should behave shuch as:

```
gcc -I. -I./list -I./sort myfile.c
```

**NOTE:** 
Please consider use `""` for your header files and use `<>` for system header files.such as :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myheader.h"
```

Comment: He's not asking how to include some file, but how to view the directories the compiler is searching when you include a file using the `#include <file>` directive

Answer (score 0):

The compiler ships with a lot of `*.h` files that depend on its exact configuration. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939930/finding-out-what-the-gcc-include-path-is) too. A general way to convince GCC/clang to own up is:

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
```

(replace `gcc` with `clang` as needed).