# How to find definition of library functions in C

Tags: c, function, header-files, definition

Functions like printf() , scanf() , memset() , puts() etc have their declaration in header files but is there any mechanism to see the definition of these function..?
This might not be a new question but i could not find the appropriate solution for this.

Comment: There is no mechanism. You have to get the source code elsewhere.

Comment: Some environments have built in, context tools, such as right clicking a standard function and selecting help from a pull down context menu.  But you can also just keep a browser page pointing to your favorite _man_ pages if Linux or MSDN if windows.

Comment: When you say definition, is it the source code, the compiled library, or a human readable description of the function? Are you looking for man-pages?

Comment: @ Leonard Michlmayr .. i am using windows... my doubt is where the compiler looks for the definition of these function while execution ?

Answer (score 5):

- Find your compilers include path (e.g. [GCC solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939930/finding-out-what-the-gcc-include-path-is))
- Search for the header you are interested in (e.g. `printf` should be in `stdio.h` or more likely another header included by `stdio.h`)
- Correctly configured, some IDEs will help you with that, e.g. Eclipse

The method has its limits though, because at some point the include files will get less and less Standard-C, but more and more compiler dependent. The C-standard does not prescribe the contents of standard headers. It merely states that if you write `#include <stdio.h>`, you can use `printf()`. That does not necessarily mean that stdio.h has some form you might expect.

Comment: What exactly is wrong about the answer?

Comment: I don't know, so I upvoted to counter the downvoter's action and restore you to +1.  Sorry it took me 5+ years to get here.