# Meaning of grave accent in gcc

Tags: gcc, sh

Following is a link to answer problem about how to find GCC include path.

[Finding out what the GCC include path is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939930/finding-out-what-the-gcc-include-path-is)

For the last answer, which is:

```
$ `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

I do not understand about the meaning of grave accent (`). Does anyone understand about its meaning?

Comment: This isn't a gcc thing, it is a shell script feature (back tick). This [SO question/answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash) may help you understand better.

Comment: The backticks are not interpreted by gcc, but by the shell.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The explanation is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The character "$" is just part of prompt.
The command

```
gcc -print-prog-name=cc1
```

is returning something like:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1
```

And now if you add the two characters ` at the beginning and end of command, output will be returned to your terminal, and you can use this as part of command.
So, for example

```
cd /home/`whoami`
```

should bring you to your home folder.
So, in your example, the command:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

is equal to:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 -v
```

which prints the version of cc1

Comment: The output isn't (necessarily) returned to the terminal. Rather, ` ``command`` ` is *replaced* by the output of `command`. And in most shells, you can use `$(command)`, which is a bit more legible and can be nested (and is a lot easier to render in Stack Overflow comments).