# Using C++ libraries on Linux dynamically and statically

Tags: c++, glfw, glew

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I cannot find answers to this anywhere.

I am new to C++ and wish to start learning OpenGL. In order to do this, I need to setup both [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/). Despite reading documentation and doing a lot of research, I cannot figure out how to utilize C++ libraries statically and dynamically. The main reason I cannot find answers to this is due to the fact I am running on Ubuntu, whereas most resources are for doing so with Windows.

I have attempted to build the libraries with [CMake](https://cmake.org/), following documentation. I appear to successfully build the libraries, but the issue then comes when using these libraries with the compiler, which again I cannot find good enough answers to.

I have tried the following steps to installing GLEW and GLFW:

- Install GLEW from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/2.1.0/).
- Install GLFW from [here](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases/download/3.3.4/glfw-3.3.4.zip).
- Unzip GLEW & GLFW
- Go into the GLEW folder
- Run `make`, `sudo make install` and `make clean` (following [this](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew#install-build-tools))
- Go into the GLFW folder
- Run `mkdir build`, `cd build` and `cmake ..` (following [this](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html))
  This is where it gets tricky.
- Run `mkdir test-project`, `mkdir test-project/dependencies`, `mkdir test-project/dependencies/include`, mkdir `test-project/dependencies/lib`
- Move `GLFW` folder in the GLFW include directory to the project includes directory
  I didn't know what I was supposed to link, so I skipped this part.
- Move `GL` folder in the GLEW include directory to the project includes directory
- Move the contents of the `lib` folder to the project `lib` directory
- Create a `main.cpp` file in the project folder
- Add this to `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

- Go to the project folder and execute `g++ ./main.cpp -I ./dependencies/include -L ./dependencies/lib`
  I then receive this error:

```
In file included from ./main.cpp:1:
./dependencies/include/GL/glew.h:1205:14: fatal error: GL/glu.h: No such file or directory
 1205 | #    include <GL/glu.h>
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Please could somebody explain how C++ libraries work dynamically and statically, how you would install a library dynamically and statically, and provide some steps to using GLEW and GLFW on Ubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share the details (ideally something approaching a [mre]) of at least one failed attempt including the error message(s). Focusing on a specific example should lead to better results than trying to explain things in general.

Comment: The compiler is looking for `GL/glu.h` under the usual system paths and `./dependencies/include` (as per the `-I` opt) and did not find one. Where did you copy it?

Comment: The structure is `test-project/dependencies/include/GL/[Header Files]`, which I believe should work.

Comment: Is it there, is it readable? We can't check the contents of your file system. If you want to get a quick listing of a directory and everything below, running `find` without arguments is a practical way of doing that. (I suggest doing one on the whole project)

Comment: @dratenik No, there is no `glu.h` in the `GL` folder, or the entire project. Strangely this doesn't come with GLEW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235883/discussion-between-samthefam-and-dratenik).

Comment: My go-to suggestion for these kinds of issues is https://github.com/Polytonic/Glitter You can figure out CMake later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Ubuntu, you can use apt to install those libraries.

1. `sudo apt install libglfw3-dev`
2. `sudo apt install libglew-dev`
3. `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev`

After these you should have GLEW and GLFW installed on your system. In order to build I would use CMake. Simply have this folder structure :

```
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

where `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test glfw GLEW /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1)
```

and `main.cpp` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
     if (!glfwInit()) {
       fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
       return 1;
     }

     GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);
     if (!window) {
       fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
       glfwTerminate();
       return 1;
     }
     glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

     glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
     glewInit();

     const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
     const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
     printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
     printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
     glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

     glfwTerminate();
     return 0;
}
```

In order to build this app

1. `cd build`
2. `cmake ..`
3. `make`
4. `./test`

*P.S: example code is taken from here : https://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html*

Update:
CMake searches for default paths for libraries. In Unix systems, they are `/usr/local/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, /usr/lib` etc. Same for include directories : `/usr/include`, `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/local/include` these are the paths used by libraries installed through package manager.
In case you want to include libraries from different paths. Let's do simple example:

I wrote a library and published it as :

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── untitled.cpp
└── untitled.h
```

where untitled.h:

```
#pragma once

class MyLibrary
{
public:
    MyLibrary();
    void doWork();
};
```

and untitled.cpp:

```
#include <untitled.h>
#include<iostream>

MyLibrary::MyLibrary()
{

}

void MyLibrary::doWork()
{
    std::cout<<"do work is called"<<std::endl;
}
```

and my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(untitled LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_library(untitled SHARED
    untitled.h
    untitled.cpp
    ) # I am generating shared library from these source files.

# Then I am telling cmake to generate Makefile so that when user does make install
# my library will be installed to folder /usr/local/untitled/
set_target_properties(untitled PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "untitled.h")
INSTALL(TARGETS untitled
    LIBRARY DESTINATION untitled/lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION untitled/include)
```

Now as a user of my library you downloaded source code and want to build for your system. You follow

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

then you run `sudo make install` . The output is like :

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/untitled/lib/libuntitled.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/untitled/include/untitled.h
```

Then you want to use this library in your project.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(test main.cpp)





# You should add these lines to your CMake file because now my library lives in an unusual path
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC /usr/local/untitled/include)
target_link_directories(test PUBLIC /usr/local/untitled/lib)

# And I have updated link_libraries section with X because there is an libX.so file
# under any of these library paths: /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib (default paths) and custom
# added library path : (usr/local/untitled/lib). In this case X is untitled.
target_link_libraries(test glfw GLEW /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 untitled)
```

and I am using library :

```
#include <untitled.h>

int main()
{
     MyLibrary ml;
     ml.doWork();

     return 0;
}
```

To see where are your include directories in your system refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939930/finding-out-what-the-gcc-include-path-is)
and to see where are your libraries in your system refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path)

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind editing this to show where I learn how to do this for other C++ libraries, I have searched for ages, and cannot find anything.